# Query from the beginning of todays date

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am trying to build a query in Marketing Cloud to find records within todays date range, so i.e. 2018-03-28 00:00:00 and 2018-03-29 00:00:00.

How can I accomplish this? Using `getdate()` actually returns the full date/time.

Comment: is your time always going to be set to  00:00:00 ?

Comment: Yes, as I want to look at between todays date and less than tomorrows date

Comment: Here's a syntax example from SFMC documentation `s.EventDate between dateadd(dd,-1,cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) and cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)`

Comment: Hi @TomCallahan, this is exactly what I needed... can you turn this into a answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a syntax example from SFMC documentation
`s.EventDate between cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) and dateadd(dd,+1,cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)`

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=5

Comment: Also FYI to make the answer more related to my question itself... the dates should be switched around and using +1 instead of -1 :-)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer this method that only uses one a single function and type conversion:

```
select
s.subscriberkey
from _sent s
where s.eventDate >= convert(date, getDate())
```

If you wanted to do a range, you can simply subtract days from `getDate()`:

```
select
s.subscriberkey
from _sent s
where s.eventDate >= convert(date, getDate()-8)
and s.eventDate < convert(date, getDate()-1)
```

If you do all of those date gymnastics on a large dataview like `_sent` there's a high likelihood your query won't complete within the 30 minute timeout window.